# Certain text containing string should return assigned value to that pattern

Tags: excel, vba, search, excel-formula

I want to display a value in a different column if the string contains some pattern in it.
For ex:
**asd_wer1**  is a string that contains *_wer* pattern in it and **ewr_jer** is the string that contains *_jer* pattern. So I want to display alan next to each string which contains _wer in it, and same for _jer also.

How can I do that?

I tried using below formula but it's not working `=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_wer",A1)),"Alan",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_jer",A1)),"Bob","")))`

I've attached the pic below for more info.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you need to look at handling the error from not found in search.

Answer (score 2):

If one has the Dynamic Formula FILTER():

```
=@FILTER($E$1:$E$2,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$1:$D$2,A2)))
```

[image]

---

If not then use:

```
=INDEX(E:E,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($D$1:$D$2)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$1:$D$2,A2))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: i tried formula with Filter, it worked for 1st row but from 2nd row its showing **SPILL**

Comment: Did you use the `@` in the beginning?

Comment: no, i used like this
=FILTER($H$2:$H$14,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$2:$G$14,A6)))

Comment: Add the `@` and it will return the first match only.  You have duplicates.

Comment: yep, now got it. 

I have one last question, can I use this formula without using the reference of second column. I mean can I just insert pattern manually which I want to match. :)

Comment: @Rushi yes you can replace the references with text arrays `{"_wer","_jer"}` and `{"Alan","Bob"}`: `=@FILTER({"Alan","Bob"},ISNUMBER(SEARCH(${"_wer","_jer"},A2)))`